# The program shows an error "the method nextInt() is undefined for the type Scanner": what should i do?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
import java.util.*;
class Scanner {
    
    public static void main(){
             
       Scanner sc = new Scanner();
       System.out.println("enter a number ");
       int a = sc.nextInt();
       System.out.println("the number you entered is "+a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rename you class to something other than Scanner. I would suggest ScannerTest.

Comment: You have tag this question as a javascript, and it is purely java try to remember this point next time.

Comment: Please remove the javascript tag. Java and javascript have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: I am not much of a java guy, but I think you wanting something like Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ==> you are missing the System.in..

Comment: Don't misquote error messages. Two spelling errors in your title.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to name class as the same as Normal Package, like Scanner. You should change your class name and the error would be gone.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Change class name,

```
 class Any_name_other_than_Scanner{
```

At Scanner definition try this,

```
Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: `Scanner`is *not* a 'reserved keyword' in Java. It is the name of the class in `java.util` that he is trying to use but has engineered a name clash with.

Comment: It is not a 'reserved class' either. It is just a class. The problem here has nothing to do with 'reserved' anything. It is just a name clash. If it was reserved in any way you would expect a compilation error saying so.